# How to change the tag placement using XSLT, but without mentioning the node name

Tags: xslt

How to change the tag placement using XSLT, but without mentioning the element name. i.e. we don't know what ar the element should be parent of `<br/>` tag.

Example: If the `<br/>` tag as a 1st child node of any element but not `<p>` or `<td>`. This case `<br/>` tag should place outside of the element. Here I have given the input and required output:

Input:

```
<p>Test <b><i><br/>case</i></b></p>
```

Required Output:

```
<p>Test <br/><b><i>case</i></b></p>
```

Comment: To format your code correctly in the question, either place the code on a separate line and indent it with four spaces (Or highlight the code and press the `{}` button in the editor). Or to show it in-line, simply put a ` symbol (a backtick) each side of the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Hi Tim, now I have edited my question, pls check and let me know in case of any further clarification required.

Comment: Tell me if I understand you. I will try to reword your question: 
a) if you match the tag "p" or "td", do nothing. 
b) If you match another tag, lets say X, and it contains the "br" tag, ouput "br" after X.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (difficult, of course, if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the (wrong?) impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: A your understanding is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need to move `<br>` as first child without preceding text up the tree to the `<p>` or `<td>` level. I have extended the examples to cover some more possible cases:

```
<test>
    <!-- these cases are ok -->
    <p>Test <br/>case</p>
    <p>Test <br/><b>case</b></p>
    <p>Test <br/><i>case</i></p>
    <p>Test <i>case<br/></i></p>
    <p>Test <b><i>case</i><br/></b></p>
    <p>Test <b><i>case<br/>case<br/></i></b></p>
    <!-- here should happen something -->
    <p>Test <b><br/>case</b></p>
    <p>Test <b><i><br/>case</i></b></p>
    <p>Test <i><br/><b>case</b></i></p>
    <!-- mixed case -->
    <p>Test <i><b><br/>case<br/></b></i></p>
    <!-- edit: additional example -->
    <p><br/><x>0.03-</x></p>
</test>
```

Now, the replacement procedure needs to components: First, removing all `br` which are in the wrong place, and secondly, create a copy of them in the desired position. Identifying the relevant `br` works this way: If a preceding-sibling or their descendant is a text node, the `br` needs to remain where it is. In other cases, it can be copied up the tree. That's it. All other elements can be copied through an identity template.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template
    match="p/*
           [descendant::br
           [not(preceding-sibling::node()
           /descendant-or-self::text())]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::br
           [not(preceding-sibling::node()
           /descendant-or-self::text())]"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--<xsl:template match="p//br
    [not(preceding-sibling::node()/descendant-or-self::text())]"/>-->
<!-- edit: fixed version -->
<xsl:template match="p/*//br
                     [not(preceding-sibling::node()
                     /descendant-or-self::text())]"/>
```

This should produce the following result:

```
<test>
    <!-- these cases are ok -->
    <p>Test <br/>case</p>
    <p>Test <br/><b>case</b></p>
    <p>Test <br/><i>case</i></p>
    <p>Test <i>case<br/></i></p>
    <p>Test <b><i>case</i><br/></b></p>
    <p>Test <b><i>case<br/>case<br/></i></b></p>
    <!-- here should happen something -->
    <p>Test <br/><b>case</b></p>
    <p>Test <br/><b><i>case</i></b></p>
    <p>Test <br/><i><b>case</b></i></p>
    <!-- mixed case -->
    <p>Test <br/><i><b>case<br/></b></i></p>
    <!-- edit: additional example -->
    <p><br/><x>0.03-</x></p>
</test>
```

Comment: `I have tested the above code, but it wrongly removed the <br/> tag which has appearing immediately followed by <p> element. ex: <p><br/><x>0.03-</x></p>`

Comment: Right, the path matched also `p/br` but it should match only `br` in descendants of `p`, so it should read `p/*//br`. Fixed that.

Comment: It is interesting to see how different two interpretations of the OP's requirements can be.

Comment: Indeed it is! Apart from our interpretations, I liked your recursive approach which saves a lot of xpath confusion. Actually, it should be possible to achieve that with functions or by using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the identity transform.  Give a name (e.g. `idt-elem`) to the template for elements.

Add a template that matches any element whose first child is a `br`.  If your input is XHTML, and you've bound the prefix `xh` to the XHTML namespace, a possible match pattern for this template is `*[child::node()[1]/self::xh:br]`.  In that template, first emit a `br` element and then call template `idt-elem`.

If this is supposed to match only elements other than `p` and `td`, then add a higher-priority for those two elements, which calls `idt-elem`.

Add a template for `br` elements which are the first child of any element other than `p` and `td`.  Make it do nothing.

The resulting stylesheet will move initial `br` elements out of their parents and make them immediate left siblings of their former parent.  To handle cases like your `<b><i><br/>...</i></b>` you will need to run the stylesheet twice.  In general, run it until its output no longer differs from its input.  (Or add a template for the root node that tests whether any `br` elements are going to be moved and issues a message otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this method and it working fine. But I expect the result in single run-time!

Comment: It is possible to perform the same procedure twice within one run-time. You would need to put the result of the first transformation into a variable (as a sequence) and then apply the transformations on that variable again.

Comment: A I tried, but it slower in process. comparing to your previous solution!